# Tiny House Sewer System Advice - Automatic Sewage Pump or Macerator Pump

Tags: pump, sewer

I'm in the process of doing some landscaping and want to run some electrical / plumbing for a future house (building next summer).

The plan right now is to have a storage tank behind or below the tiny house for waste water then pump it 60' or so to the main house's sewer line.  I'm debating between the following (pretty similar):

**Automatic Sewage Pump**

These are usually used for basement bathrooms where the main sewer line is above the plumbing. It consists of a tank with a pump inside of it. When the pump detects the water level has reached a certain height, it automatically turns on and pumps out all the waste in the tank through 2" pipes (usually vertically).

Pros:

- Runs automatically
- Tried and tested in many homes

Cons:

- Doesn't macerate (cut up) waste at all, worry it could get stuck somewhere along the 60' of pipe or something.
- I have 1.5" pipe sitting around. Poor excuse, but would be nice to get rid of it.

**Macerating Pump**

These are more often used to pump out waste from RVs. They connect to the holding tank (externally, as opposed to internally for the sewage pump). When you turn them on they'll macerate (cut up into 1/8" pieces) and pump the sewage out through the 3/4" output.

Pros:

- Macerates to reduce chance of clogging.
- Need smaller pipe (only 3/4")
- Pump is external (easier/less messy to maintain / replace).

Cons:

- Not automatic. Could wire to a switch and many have sensor to detect moisture so it'll automatically turn off. But still, not automatic.
- Haven't really seen them used in house (tiny or big) at all.

Anyone got any experience with either of these? Any feedback? Any suggestions?

Thanks all!